# Why is Alfred being loyal to Superman here?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, zack-snyders-justice-league

In Zack Snyder's Justice League, Alfred meets Superman for first time:

> Superman: I'm assuming you're Alfred.
>
> Alfred: **Master Kent**. [He](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman) said you'd come.

Why is Alfred being loyal to Superman here?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'loyal' in the context given. Do you mean by calling him "Master"? That's just another way a fancy butler would say "Sir" to an official guest, or demi-god - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_(form_of_address)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Master" is simply the proper butler adress to guests:

Master Bruce (Batman)

Master Grayson (Robin/Nightwing)

Master Jones (Martian Manhunter)

Master Allen (Flash)

Miss Gordon (Batgirl)

He calls every visitor Master. In fact in the injustice comics, him no longer calling Superman "Master Kent" was a plotpoint indicating the loss of friendship between Batman and Superman.